# Big O - Equivalence: "Standard" definition vs Limit definition

Tags: terminology, asymptotics, landau-notation

This question is related to: [Landau Notation, Definitions: Limits vs. Cormen's](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10531/landau-notation-definitions-limits-vs-cormans?rq=1).

Consider functions $f, \ g : N \rightarrow R^{\geq0}$.

For small-$o$, the definition:
$$f(n)\in o(g(n)) \iff \forall c>0,\exists n_0>0, \forall n\geq n_0: f(n) < c \ g(n)$$

Can also be expressed as a limit (i guess this assumes the limit exists):
$$f(n)\in o(g(n)) \iff \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0 $$

This can be verified introducing the definition for $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ on $N$, and then both definitions are identical.

Now, the "standard" definition for big-O would be something like (near exactly to Cormen's, except the codomain here is $R^{\geq0}$):
$$f(n)\in O(g(n)) \iff \exists c>0,\exists n_0>0, \forall n\geq n_0: f(n) \leq c \ g(n)  \qquad  (1)$$

Im trying to see if the following is true (again, this assumes the limit exists):
$$f(n)\in O(g(n)) \stackrel{?}{\iff} \exists c>0: \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=c$$

Im not sure both directions of the equivalence are true. More specifically, i am having trouble with the $\Rightarrow$. According to [this general answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth), both directions should be true for $\Theta(g(n))$, wich is stronger than $O(\_)$. On the contrary, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545144/limit-definition-for-big-o) (for roughly the same question, but in math SE) says big-$O$ cant be defined in that way (it was downvoted).

So, the questions are:

1. How exactly def (1) implies the $\lim$ definition?:

$$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists n_0>0, \forall n\geq n_0: \left| \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}-c\right| < \epsilon$$

2. Is the above still true considering generic functions $f, \ g : X \rightarrow R^{\geq0}$, where $X$ is some reasonable domain, maybe $Z$, $N^k$ or even $R^k$ (although reals are not turing-computable, im thinking in algorithms in the more general sense possible).

Comment: Second, in the the proposed equivalence, you are missing that $c = 0$ implies $f \in o(g) \subsetneq O(g)$.

Comment: In summary, read the definitions more carefully, and you're good.

Comment: @Raphael For your first comment, my $o$ definition is $\forall c ...$, the $O$ definition is $\exists c ...$, so i don't get what you mean with "you effectively define O". For the second, the proposed definition of $O$ with limits is with $c>0$. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: 1) Sorry, missed the different quantifier. Never mind. 2) Right, and that's why the equivalence doesn't hold. If such $c \in (0,\infty)$ exists, you have $f \in \Theta(g)$. You may want to read [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/827/98). (Also, be aware that there are $f \in O(g)$ for which the limit does not exist, so the limit "definition" is not at all a definition.)

Comment: @Raphael Yes, one of the cited links in the question is to your answer, where you state that if If $c \in (0,\infty)$ exists then $f \in \Theta(g)$, but this also implies that $f \in O(g)$ and $f \in \Omega(g)$. So, let see if i finally get this, the $\Leftarrow$ direction holds, because if $f \in O(g)$ and  $f \in \Theta(g)$ then is evident $f \in O(g)$, but the $\Rightarrow$ direction doesn't hold because if $f \in O(g)$, it doesn't implies also that $f \in \Theta(g)$.

Comment: About the "limit definition", if we consider lim sup/inf, then it is a definition or not?. A periodic function doesn't have limit, but there exists some algorithm with a cost function over some measure in wich the function is not monotonous increasing?.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes, as I state in that other answer, lim sup provides an equivalent definition. 3) Yes. More importantly, many have oscillating components; if we want to bound those contributes ("error terms") using O, the definition should capture "limitless" functions as well.

Comment: @Raphael (3) Interesting, can you give me an example of an algorithm with that characteristics? (i assume you are considering "time" complexity).

Comment: An algorithm that computes $n \mapsto n+1$ would be a popular example (in the bit-cost model). As for oscillating lower-order contributions, [Mergesort is one example](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2390/98).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f = O(g)$ then there exists $C>0$ such that for large enough $n$, we have $f(n)/g(n) \leq C$. Hence under mild assumptions,
$$
f = O(g) \Longleftrightarrow \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \infty.
$$
As Raphael mentions in a comment to your post, your definition is symmetric in $f,g$ and so is more appropriate for $\Theta$.

Comment: mmm.. i thought it was not an equivalence after all, also the  comment on the post say the "equivalence doesn't hold" (but it does for $\Theta$), i'm missing something in your answer?. Also, what you mean with "mild assumptions"?, and why you write "... $ < \infty$" instead of just "... $= C$"? they don't mean the same thing?.

Comment: The main difference between your definition and mine is that mine uses the limit superior rather than the limit. The equivalence should hold under mild assumptions such as $f,g$ being eventually positive. Finally, I write $<\infty$ since I don't care about the value of the limit superior, as long as its finite.

Comment: Ok, i see my def was to restrictive with the $c>0$ condition. So, assuming the lim exists, is your def equivalent to: $\exists c\geq0: \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=c$ ?. By the way, sorry but i cant vote you.

Comment: You should be able to answer this question on your own.

Comment: I am not really familiarized with lim sup/inf. Most class notes doesn't mention it, or is treated like some peculiarity.

Comment: That's a great opportunity to get to know this stuff.

Comment: Ok, can you give an example of a real algorithm with oscillating cost behavior?. I would think in general they are  monotonous increasing.

Comment: Mergesort. Any divide and conquer algorithm is sensitive to the input length, specifically to what extend it can be divided evenly at every level of the recursion. By the way, oscillations are possible even if the running time is monotone. If you're interested in this question, I suggest asking it as a new question.

Comment: Right, i will ask a new question.